# Question mark showed instead of special character

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am fetching data from mysql server but the data contains some special character which when i try to print through my php code show a question mark instead. I know this has something to do with character encoding, and i have set charset to utf-8 in my html code but still I am not getting the special characters.

Comment: What collation your database table is using?

Comment: latin1_swedish_ci collation

Comment: Try changing it to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: there are 22 tables in the database, and have loads of data, is this the onliy choice??

Comment: Try changing only for one table. If it works you can write sql to change for other tables too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8") to the start of the php code after the db connection.

Comment: is that mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")??

Comment: yess!! thanks buddy , i've tried this and it works like magic... thanks a ton.. :)